# How do I get a trigger on a record selection?

Tags: ms-access, events, vba, ms-access-2016, splitview

I have a splitview form in Access 2016 pictured here
[image: Splitview with datasheet below]

The [Category] and [Location] combo-boxes need a row source update whenever a new record is selected on the datasheet. I have all the code finished for the row source changes but I can't find an event to trigger it. The code is currently linked to that silly [Command10] button because I cannot find anything that triggers on a record selection change. The main field that dictates the row sources is the [Discrepancy Type].

All of the text boxes update as they should when a record is selected in the datasheet so there must be something going on I can trigger off of but I'll be dipped if I can find it. I have been tossing msgbox flags on every form event and textbox event I can possibly imagine could relate but to no avail. Many events that sound like they would work seem to only apply to pivot tables.

I want to run the row source update every time the user selects a different record.

This seems like it should be obvious but I'm not finding anything in forums and it seems very few people use SplitView forms.

Comment: can you post the code plz?!

Comment: can you be more specific? how did you achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

On Current was the event trigger I was looking for. It just would never have occurred to me to call it that. Way to go Microsoft. The description text says "Macro or Function that runs when focus moves from one record to another." Woof.

Comment: It means when the 'Current' record changes. Hence the event name.

Comment: the reason i do not like on current is because it also follows you around as you use keyboard directional keys up or down the records. If only there was something like record click.